# AUTO_INCREMENT по группам

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как создать авто_инкриментальную колонку в таблице по группе?

Пример:

```
id  name   group_field
1   test   1
2   test2  1
1   test3  2
2   test4  2
1   test5  3
2   test6  3
```

Последовательность id идет в рамках каждой группы. Нашел решение для таблицы на движке MyISAM, но нужно решение для InnoDB.

Comment: боюсь только тиггером с хранением последних id для каждой группы в отдельной таблице

Comment: @Mike, а зачем отдельная таблица?

Comment: @Qwertiy У большинства БД проблемы с чтением таблицы на которую сделан триггер в теле самого триггера. У MySQL может и можно но всяких граблей с этим я обычно опасаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Бесполезно. Автоинкремент в принципе не гарантирует, что индексы будут идти подряд, а значит можно не заморачиваться и делать автоинкремент, не зависящий от групп.